# Remove the default help command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to remove the default help command from my bot, but I'm running into some issues. I used remove_command('help'), but it didn't work. It's still giving me this error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.help' raised an error: CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.

Can someone help me?

Code:

```py
from discord import ActivityType, AllowedMentions
from bot.Logging import Logging
from discord.ext import commands
import logging
import discord
import config



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s - %(name)s] %(message)s")
logging.getLogger("discord").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

bot = Logging(commands.when_mentioned_or(*config.prefixes),
                    case_insensitive=True,
                    owner_ids=config.owner_ids,
                    activity=discord.Activity(name=f"Over The Server", type=ActivityType.watching),
              remove_command=('help'),


                    # Regular client settings
                    max_messages=None,
                    intents=discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True),
                    allowed_mentions=AllowedMentions.none())


bot.run(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it using on a **sperate line**

```py
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error when I do that.

Comment: How about you use it outside of your cog at the first time you define the `bot`